# How can I Test Nested Condition in query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my data which showing in a table. 
    I want update my table like below giving scenario-

1. First I have to check max sodate then update all matching group work with that cluster which have max sodate.
2. If sodate is  not available then I have to check max sodateany then update all matching group work with that cluster which have max sodateany.
3. If sodateany not available then I have to check max lastedate then update all matching group work with that cluster which have max lastedate

I/P Table

```
work         |cluster       |       sodate      |sodateany          |   lastedate          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1st scenario 
-------------
22356894     | 123645       |      2014-05-07   |   2015-05-17      |   2015-03-16               
22356894     | 126          |      2014-05-05   |   2015-05-18      |   2015-03-17                
22356894     | 145          |      2014-04-03   |   2015-04-17      |   2015-03-18                

2nd scenario 
------------

24432464     | 456          |       -----       |       2015-05-17  |       2015-03-16                
24432464     | 321          |      2014-05-05   |   2015-05-18      |   2015-03-17                
24432464     | 215          |      2014-04-03   |   2015-04-17      |   2015-03-18                

3rd scenario
-------------
24432423     | 987          |       --          |   2015-05-17      |   2015-03-16                 
24432423     | 56           |       --          |   2015-05-18      |   2015-03-17                

4th scenario
-------------
24432412     |326           |   --              |--                 |2015-03-16                 
24432412     |576           |   --              | 2015-05-18        |   2015-03-17                 

5th scenario
-------------|--            |                   |                   |
24432423     |326           |   --              |--                 |2015-03-16                             
24432423     |305           |   --              | --                |   2015-03-17
```

o/p looking like

---

This output comming by using below scenario.

1)First I have to check max sodate then update all matching group work with that cluster which have max sodate.

2) If sodate is  not available then I have to check max sodateany then update all matching group work with that cluster which have max sodateany.

3)If sodateany not available then I have to check max lastedate then update all matching group work with that cluster which have max lastedate.

O/P Table

```
work            |cluster        |       sodate      |      sodateany|               lastedate          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1st scenario   
------------    
22356894        |123645         |    2014-05-07     |2015-05-17     |   2015-03-16               
22356894        |123645         |   2014-05-05      |2015-05-18     |   2015-03-17                
22356894        |123645         |    2014-04-03     |2015-04-17     |   2015-03-18                

2nd scenario   
-------------   
24432464        |321            |   -----           |2015-05-17     |   2015-03-16                
24432464        |321            |      2014-05-05   |   2015-05-18  |       2015-03-17               
24432464        |321            |    2014-04-03     |2015-04-17     |   2015-03-18                

3rd scenario 
------------    
24432423        |56             |      --           |   2015-05-17  |       2015-03-16                
24432423        |56             |       --          |   2015-05-18  |       2015-03-17                

4th scenario    
------------    
24432412        |576            |   --              |--             |   2015-03-16                 
24432412        |576            |   --              | 2015-05-18    |       2015-03-17                 

5th scenario   
------------   
24432423        |305            |   --              |--             |   2015-03-16                             
24432423        |305            |   --              | --            |       2015-03-17
```

Thanks

Comment: `then update all matching group` Update *what* ? what is *matching group* ?

Comment: Hmm... I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you are after.  Is the table you provide the intended output? If so, can you also provide some of the input?

Comment: Hi, David first table is input table and the second table is output table.Here the matching group is work column.In one matching group have different cluster .I have to update cluster to this matching work group as a single cluster .For updating the cluster we have to first check  max sodate  .If max sodate is available then whose cluster have max date will assign to all work matching group .as shown first scenario -22356894 is work in one group have different cluster.In this work group max sodate is 2014-05-07  ,

Comment: so whose cluster have this max sodate will assign in this work group ,so here cluster 123645  have max sodate so this cluster assign to this particular work group.Same thing will apply in rest scenario.I mention above three condition according to that we have to update work group.